# Ubuntu 15.04 apt-get error messages

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

Always when I run `sudo apt-get-update` I get the error messages below. how can I fix that ?

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found 
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: remove ppa    `chris-lea/node.js`   file from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: tks. problem solved.

Comment: accept answer by clicking on tick mark on left side of answer that will be helpful for other who face this type of problem .

Answer (score 1):

you have added ppa for `node.js` and currently that is not available on that link . thats why is it giving `404 Not Found` error. you can see [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/). there is no `vivid` repository.

**solution :**

remove that ppa file from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` or if there is no file related  `chris-lea/node.js` then open file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and search entry related `chris-lea/node.js` and delete that line .
then do update

```
sudo apt-get update
```